# Using selenium in firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

Hello I want to click OK on a download popup window, however when I try

```
drive = selenium.selenium.selenium()
drive.choose_ok_on_next_confirmation()
```

It gives me an error `AttributeError: type object 'selenium' has no attribute 'selenium'`. I have alread tried setting the MIME type for preferences but it does not work.

Comment: So what line does it fail on? if it fails on `drive = selenium.selenium.selenium()` then i would assume that you have one to many `selenium`...

Comment: But if I do `selenium.selenium` it is still not there.

Comment: are you using webdriver or RC?

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the selenium module?

A quick google search finds this page: [Selenium RC with Python in 30 seconds](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/09/selenium-rc-with-python-in-30-seconds.html). The code at the bottom of that page is a minimal example of how to get a selenium instance up and running.

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear what you are using here exactly but assuming you are just using the selenium remote control you should be able to do

```
from selenium import selenium
```

followed by

```
sel = selenium("localhost", 4444, "firefox", "http://www.google.com")
```

or something similar.  you should really take a closer look at the [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html)